# Using xlswrite for extracting results in two columns

Tags: matlab

I am trying to extract the result of Matlab in to an excel or notepad text file. I drew a graph on Matlab using set of equations and the output is the set of 'v' values on x-axis and set of corresponding 'p' values on y-axis. I would like to save the resultant values in to a separate .txt or excel file. I wrote the code as follows;

```
data_name = {'v','P'};
data_value1 = [v];
data_value2 = [P];
xlswrite('output.xlsx',data_name,1,'A1');
xlswrite('output.xlsx',data_value1,1,'A2');
xlswrite('output.xlsx',data_value2,1,'B2');
```

The output in excel I am getting for the above code is like this,
[image]

I intend to get the values of 'v' in the column A while as the values of 'P' in volumn B. With each column having the first row of text 'v' and 'P' respectively. Can someone please help to correct the coding.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply transpose the vector that contains the values of v.

```
data_name = {'v','P'};
data_value1 = [v];
data_value2 = [P];
xlswrite('output.xlsx',data_name,1,'A1');
xlswrite('output.xlsx',data_value1',1,'A2'); % Transpose!
xlswrite('output.xlsx',data_value2,1,'B2');
```

Matlab writes an xls file taking into account the structure of the vector or matrix.